# Scene takes 20secs to load because of StandaloneInputModule

Tags: unity-game-engine, profiling

My main scene is taking 20 secs to load and after running the profiler it points to `StandaloneInputModule` as what makes it take that time.

I've searched in project for that script but it does not exist, i've only found a `StandaloneInput`
[image]

¿Where can i find this script/reduce this load time?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with StandaloneInput....Are you using AseetBudle or are you using any async load function? What platform is this problem happening on?

Comment: Nope i don't use AssetBundle and i've searched for `.Async` or `.LoadLevelAsync` but returns 0 results. Platform PC | Unity 2017.01.b9

Comment: How about `Resources.LoadAsync`? You are using *Unity 2017.01*.... I think you should file for a bug report.

Comment: 0 results too (I also stopped using Resources folder, it only has 5 pngs now) :( I will try updating to b10, maybe it fixes the problem.

Comment: Didn't work, i changed the way we load the UI. (Game scene -> Menu scene [has the dontDestroyOnLoadCanvas] -> Previous Game scene)  to Game scene -> load canvas prefab. I do not longer have this 20secs load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StandaloneInputModule is in the Event System  GameObject that you have in your project and it's the responsable of your input in the game that you are developing :)

The problem is essentially that you may have a ton of  world space UI Canvases in your game. Each of these canvases has a "graphics raycaster" script, because I think they're put there automatically when you create a canvas (could be wrong). Just remove all of those graphic raycasting checks on all of those canvases. The event system was having to try to keep track of all of those objects, and thus the "Eventsystem.Update()" was having a really hard time. Getting rid of those "graphic raycaster" scripts freed up a ton of CPU time in my game.

The good news is that the "Event System" script and the "Input module" script are not terrible for performance in and of themselves. This is great news for me, because I thought it was on Unity's end, and it turns out not to be (unless you need a lot of graphic raycaster checks).

Peace!

Comment: I have 1 scene with a Canvas (which has all game menus) and it has DontDestroyOnLoad, so we only have 1 Canvas with everything that "travels" on any scene change :S

http://imgur.com/5O4KSNR

Comment: @FrakyDale : Make sure all your non-clickable UI elements does not have "Raycast target" enabled. For example texts inside buttons (since the buttons' image are already raycast targets)

Comment: @Hellium done, i didn't notice any improvement in loading times :(